# Docker build fails when untar a large file citing not enough space, how do I increase?

Tags: docker, dockerfile

Within my Dockerfile I'm running a tar command to untar a large file. It stops with an error saying there is not enough free space.
`Docker info` provides:

```
Data Space Used: 10.99GB
 Data Space Total: 107.4GB
 Data Space Available: 28.89GB
 Metadata Space Used: 8.892MB
 Metadata Space Total: 2.147GB
 Metadata Space Available: 2.139GB
 Thin Pool Minimum Free Space: 10.74GB
```

Which one ofthese do I need to increase, and how do I do it. This file when unpacked will be <10GB so my HDD will have plenty of space.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can expand maximum container disk size:

- Rigth Click Docker icon
- Settings > Daemon
- Toggle to Advanced
- Add this property:

  {
    "storage-opts": [
      "size=120GB"
    ]
  }

You should now see:

```
{
  "registry-mirrors": [],
  "insecure-registries": [],
  "debug": true,
  "experimental": false,
  "storage-opts": [
    "size=120GB"
  ]
}
```

- Click Apply.

This should work for Windows 10.

Answer (score 0):

If you have been using docker for a while make sure to do some cleanup using:

```
docker system prune -f --volumes
```